# In an Angular library can you build a specific entry point to save time on builds?

Tags: angular, angular-library

Building a huge library with multiple entry points after doing a small change takes a lot of time. Can we instead build only the entry point that we updated and maybe the compiler builds that portion of the library and others only if they are needed to build this one?

Comment: You can try to use new esbuild builder in Angular 16 or switch to Nx which has better cache.

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using? Starting in Angular 13 there is quite a bit more compile-time caching.

Comment: at the moment we are using Angular 10

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option **watch**, then only the subentry that you update will be rebuilt, automatically:

`ng build <projectName> --watch`

Obs:

Watching files takes more memory. If your project is too big that you run out of memory during build process, add to your root `package.json` scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "watch": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --watch --configuration development",
    ...
  }
```

Adjust the amount of memory to your needs. Then run the watch command from your root as

`npm run watch <projectName>`